# Bidirectional level translator using N channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, physics, open-drain, body-diode

[image]

I'm using a n channel MOSFETa bidirectional level translator. The case when the body diode conducts the source end will be literally 0V or forward voltage of body diode, so the difference in voltage across gate to source will be enough to form a channel.

My question is: few seconds after the GPIO 1 pulls down, whether the channel between source to drain starts to conduct or not ?

[image]

Comment: The picture doesn't look like one.

Comment: yes it's not exact level translator, i have simplified it for the case i have mentioned.

Comment: The voltage at the source will never exceed ~ 0.6 V. What is the purpose of using a MOSFET like that? This circuit basically draws some current from the right VCC2P8 and it will draw slightly more current when the left VCC2P8 is present. I do not see how this circuit will do anything useful.

Comment: Unless you are 100% convinced that simplifying the circuit doesn't change anything relevant, just **don't simplify** your circuit. I have seen plenty of questions here where the simplification removed relevant parts that were causing the actual issue or the parts that were removed were **crucial** to the operation of the circuit. If you have to ask when the MOSFET conducts etc. then usually you're not fully understanding the circuit and it will be better to include everything for clarity.

Comment: i have simplified it because it is a open drain buffer, while the gpio at the drain side pulls down it is ideally a ground point that's why is mentioned like that, since my doubt is regarding whether the diode conducts or channel conducts i removed things which does not have any effect in my question.

Comment: i have included the actual picture too

Comment: The complete circuit looks more sensible and like a circuit that will work. Now I recognize it and understand how it's supposed to work (contrary to the simplified version which looked like a pointless circuit). Next time just include the complete circuit and just mention that you ask about the situation where GPIO1 is pulled to ground.

Comment: When GPIO1 is pulled to ground, for the NMOSFET: Vd = 0 V, Vs = ~0.6 V (due to diode, for now assuming NMOSFET is not conducting), Vg = 2.8 V so Vgs = ~ 2.2 V which means the NMOSFET will be **on**, there will be a low ohmic channel between drain and source. This will short the diode so Vs = 0 V. So yes, the MOSFET will switch on as well. That will pull GPIO2 low as well like it is supposed to be.

Comment: thank you @Bimpelrekkie, but i having a doubt, does a mosfet conducts from source to drain ??

Comment: When the channel is formed, there is a low resistance connection between drain and source. So it is like there's a small value resistor between drain and source. I suggest you study the theory of operation of MOSFETs and learn that drain and source are actually **the same**, what we call drain or source is actually determined by the **direction of the current** through the MOSFET.

Comment: thank you @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103073/discussion-between-vignesh-c-and-bimpelrekkie).

Answer (score 0):

The body diode saves you in that scenario.  Your source is pulled down to ~0.65V through the body diode.  Assuming your gate threshold on the FET is under 2.15V, that will enable the channel which will immediately pull it down the rest of the way.